# Import folder as module in a Node.js project like we do in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, express

I have been learning express and I want to use it with ES6 syntax without using require to import modules. But I have been facing errors when I try to do that.
Here is my folder tree -

```
.
├── app.js
├── package.json
└── tt
    └── index.js
```

Contents of app.js :

```
import f from "./tt";
```

Contents of tt/index.js :

```
export default function tt() {
  console.log("tt");
}
```

Contents of package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hehe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When I run `node app.js` I get the following error :

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:97
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import '/mnt/devv/rootdir/tt' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /mnt/devv/rootdir/app.js
```

If I import `./tt/index.js` in `app.js` instead of importing `./tt`, it works fine.
But I was wondering if there's any way to make it work like React Native where we can import index.js of a folder by just importing the folder itself.